# Two seperate docker php environments one shared mysql

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am SUPER new to Docker and have spent 4-5 hrs trying to figure this out with no luck so I am turning to you docker geniuses.

I currently have multiple websites, each with their own docker container. Each container is a full environment I created using the Docker documentation - PHP, Ubuntu, Mysql, Server (nginx / apache). Though this works, it isn't what I need / want in the long run.

I have a several Laravel sites running php7 and ngnix with mysql. I also have a couple Phalcon php 5.5 containers using apache and mysql. For each site I have a container built from a base like [this webdevops](http://dockerfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/DockerImages/dockerfiles/php-apache-dev.html) then using the exec command went in and added the laravel stuff or Phalcon stuff.

The problem is that many times I need to reference multiple databases as once. The sites aren't linked but I need a quick look at a db from another project. I also need to run a new container for EACH site, which is stupid because all Laravel sites have the EXACT same environment.

What I would love is to have a mysql container with all my databases. A container with my php7 and nginx for ALL my laravel sites and a container with php 5.5 and apache for ALL my Phalcon stuff. This lets me just look at the code in one environment (without running the environment) AND see the tables in the database while running the other environment. Ie running environment container A that has sites 1, 2, 3 mapped and a shared mysql container. So I can see sites 3, 4 databases without running environment container B

I tried creating yaml files in each project and having a shared dir with envrionment dockerfiles but that isn't working. I have used the likes of [this](http://laradock.io/), and [this](https://github.com/micooz/docker-lnmp/) and [this](https://github.com/nanoninja/docker-nginx-php-mysql/) to try and guide me but no luck.

Can anyone give me some pointers on where to start or help me with a super simple base example of how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you need to access a different site's database? Why figure out how to run multiple sites in one container- one great thing about Docker is the the ability to isolate environments without wasting resources-

Comment: The company I work for often asks random questions on a whim. 'what field stores X Data?', 'what are the last 10 values in X table?', 'can you quickly test this function?' etc. This leaves me starting and stopping containers constantly. It's annoying